# MySQL web customer activity analysis question

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I created a very simple toy table:
[image]

Use the following MySQL script to create the same table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `sessionid` int NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


LOCK TABLES `test` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (1,'2020-01-01 05:00:00','../1/..',1),(1,'2020-01-01 05:02:00','../2/..',2),(1,'2020-01-01 05:08:00','../1/..',3),(1,'2020-01-01 05:12:00','../4/..',4),(2,'2020-01-01 05:00:00','../1/..',5),(2,'2020-01-01 06:00:00','../2/..',6),(3,'2020-01-01 05:00:00','../2/..',7),(3,'2020-01-01 05:03:00','../1/..',8),(3,'2020-01-01 05:04:00','../2/..',9);
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I'd like to query:

(1) In `10` minutes time span, which `sessionid` has visited url `../1/..` then visited url `../2/..`?
**Answer: session 1, 3**

(2) In `10` minutes time span, which `sessionid` has visited url `../1/..` then visited url `../2/..`, and finally landed back to url `../1/..`?
**Answer: session 1**

I would appreciate it if you can write in MySQL. Provide code or simply give some strategy thoughts about solving this will be great.

Comment: I removed the inappropriate database tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions.  For instance, for "2":

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when url like '%/2/%' then timestamp end) over (partition by id order by timestamp desc) as next_2,
             min(case when url like '%/3/%' then timestamp end) over (partition by id order by timestamp desc) as next_3
      from t
     ) t
where url like '%/1/%' and
      next_2 < timestamp + interval 10 minute;
```

Comment: Would you please explain this in detail? Why do you create the `next_3` column?

Comment: @o_yeah . . . So you can do a comparison for the "3" url as the question also asks.  This is an example for "2".

Comment: Buddy, you are a genius. I'm pretty new to SQL, I really can't imagine how you think so fast.. Would you mind sharing how you practice SQL queries?

Comment: @o_yeah . . . I have lots of experience working with data.